How to Model Stake's : "Mines Gambling Game"
Mines is a gambling game on stake that I came across after watching a streamer play it. There are 25 tiles, and the player has the option to choose between 1-24 mines to be randomly placed under the tiles. You flip tiles one by one, hoping to avoid the mines, and you can either cash out at your own discretion or "go for broke" and try to flip all the tiles except the bombs. Of course, if you hit a bomb, you lose. I was curious about the probabilities of winning depending on how many mines you choose and how many tiles you flip. I have not concerned myself with the pay rates yet, but I just wanted a basic look into the statistics. I have an equation, which I have answered below. My primary goal is to post the answer for the sake of having it exist. However, I would love feedback on better ways to model this, and perhaps pointers on how one would begin to factor pay rates into this. For reference, this website has the necessary data (albeit from a different site offering the same game) and displays the return rates, but unfortunately it is presented in Cleo-esque fashion, lol.

The equation I came up with is the following:
$$y=\frac{(25-b)!}{25!} \cdot \frac{(25-x)!}{((25-b)-x)!}$$
Where b represents the number of mines and x is the turn you are on. Here it is implemented onto Desmos.
The fraction on the left is what gets the product of the probabilities of flipping a tile each turn, and the fraction on the right is what lets us view the probability at each turn (as opposed to playing only "for broke" and flipping everything except the bombs, which is what the left fraction would show if viewed alone)

Your answer is correct.

@awkward thanks for the verification!

Stake.us computes the payoff in 'Mines' as the bet multiplied by the inverse of the probability of flipping  tiles without hitting a mine, given  mines:

First turn: The probability of flipping a safe tile is:
$$ \frac{25 - m}{25} $$

Second turn: The probability becomes:
$$ \frac{25 - m - 1}{25 - 1} $$


The general formula:
$$
P(x) = \prod_{n=0}^{x-1} \frac{25 - b - n}{25 - n}
$$

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
